# _InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>' in type cast

Tags: dart, flutter

I have the error from the Title when trying to do this

1. I have this kind of json where the first parameter is a unique key

   ```
   {
     "3dfb71719a11693760f91f26f4f79c3c": {
       "a": {
         "var1": {
           "value": "8678468,4,2,2,0,0",
           "time": 1544536734000
         },
         "var2": {
           "value": "8678468,4,2,2,0,0",
           "time": 1544536734000
         },
         ...
       },
       "b": {
         "var3": {
           "value": "8678468,4,2,2,0,0",
           "time": 1544536734000
         },
         ...
       },
       "c": {
         "var4": {
           "value": "8678468,4,2,2,0,0",
           "time": 1544536734000
         },
         ...
       }
     },
     "c91891522a8016fc8a097b9e405b118a": {
       "a": {
         ...
       },
       "b": {
         ...
       },
       "c": {
         ...
       }
     }
   }
   ```
2. I created @JsonSerialiazable() class to handle the json

   ```
   @JsonSeriazable()
   class MyResponse {
     final List<AType> a;
     final List<BType> b;
     final List<Ctype> c;

     MyResponse(this.a, this.b, this.c);

     factory MyResponse.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$MyResponseFromJson(json);
   }

   class AType {
       final StringValueTime var1;
       final StringValueTime var2;
       ...

       AType(this.var1, this.var2, ...);

       factory AType.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => $_ATypeFromJson(json);
   }
   ```
3. Then, when calling the http.get(), I do this:

   ```
   Map<String, dynamic> map = json.decode(response.body);
   List<MyResponse> myObjects = List<MyResponse>();

   final keys = map.keys;

   keys.forEach((id) {
     final MyResponse obj = MyResponse.fromJson(map[id]);
     myOjects.add(obj);
   });
   ```

The map variable looks like this:

```
    0: "3dfb71719a11693760f91f26f4f79c3c"
        key: "3dfb71719a11693760f91f26f4f79c3c"
        value: <Map (3 items)>
          0: "a" <Map x items>
             key: "a"
             value: <Map x items>
          1: "b" <Map x items>
          2: "c" <Map x items>
    1: "c91891522a8016fc8a097b9e405b118a"
```

When _$MyResponseFromJson(json) is called it gives me the error when it tries to do (json['a'] as List) from my_response.g.dart file generated by the build_runner.

```
    MyResponse _$MyResponseFromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
      return MyResponse(
          (json['a'] as List)
              ?.map((e) =>
                  e == null ? null : AType.fromJson(e as Map<String, dynamic>))
              ?.toList(),
```

How can I fix the error?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my issue with the help of @Irn. The class should be like this

```
    @JsonSeriazable()
    class MyResponse {
      final AType a;
      final BType b;
      final Ctype c;

      MyResponse(this.a, this.b, this.c);

      factory MyResponse.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$MyResponseFromJson(json);
    }

    class AType {
        final StringValueTime var1;
        final StringValueTime var2;
        ...

        AType(this.var1, this.var2, ...);

        factory AType.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => $_ATypeFromJson(json);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `a`, `b` and `c` fields are typed as *lists*, but the JSON does not have a list at that position, just a single value (as a map).

So, check whether you actually do want the fields to be lists, or whether they should just be single values of the element type.

Comment: Hi @Irn, thanks for the hint. I thought the 'a' would be considered as a list of objects, no? I understand that when looking to the map result, it looks like a single value, but in fact there are other objects below. I just don't know how to convert that json. Maybe my class are not defined right? Suggestion? I also updated section 2 with more code.